# TYPO3 multidomain template / theme settings

Tags: templates, themes, typo3, settings, config

We will have a TYPO3 system with multi domains. Each domain has a little bit different template options, footer contents inc. images and of course detail pids. I ask myself, where the best place should be, to store this information. Also the editor should edit them. TypoScript constants is not the way I prefere. Because the pids are in the database maybe the config should also be there? Actually I think about an own table. About feedback I would be very happy.

Comment: "Detail pids" for what and why editor must edit them?
Why not set constant uids of content element for footer?
You can make some simple FCE wrapper to group content elements in it (ie. for footer), then set the uid of it into typoscript or fluid template to use as footer (pid non editable) and then the editor can just edit contents inside this wrapper, without the need to configure any pids at all.
And why not typoscript constants? If you need to, just use them.
Please explain your approach, I'm afraid I don't get the whole point.

Comment: Thanks for your responce. I want to be more flexible. We have a development environment and a live one. The detail pids etc. are different. I don't whant to use TypoScript conditions because of performance. Of course the editor should not edit them. But the content he should. A FCE which I needed only one time is also not the best case. Because I don't use flexforms, I have to extend the tt_content table then too much. I like the idea to have every template related config in one place. Also there will be about 8 different templates/domains. So a new domain should be set up easily...

Answer (score 0):

This is common problem in such cases. Simple solution for this may be like this.
Make some global typoscript configuration for such settings, which will keep pids etc. per domain, like:

```
# default
site {
    PID {
        search = 1
        footer = 2
    }
}

[hostname = stage.myhostname.tld]
# [applicationContext = Stage]
site {
    PID {
        search = 3
        footer = 5
    }
}
[hostname = myhostname.tld]
# [applicationContext = Production]
site {
    PID {
        search = 4
        footer = 7
    }
}
[global]
```

define this as setup or constants and just use in normal typoscript assigns

```
plugin.someplugin.somepid < site.PID.search
```

or

```
plugin.someplugin.somepid = {$site.PID.search}
```

Comment: Thanks. But as I said I will avoid TypoScript Conditions because of performance.

Comment: You should not afraid of such small conditions, it's only one condition with all settings at once. I had many more in huge sites and it doesn't affect performance.
Also remember it's all cached if you didn't disable caching, so it doesn't parse this condition very often.

Comment: Ok. And how to solve the problem with the content for editors?

Answer (score 0):

As normal editors have no access to typoscript all the configuration an editor can do must be stored either in the database or in files in `fileadmin/`.

If you want a configuration be valid for a whole page tree you must store the information in a way you could assign it to the tree. Therefore my suggestion is: use fields in table pages or special content columns. These values can be inherited (slide).
Either reuse existing fields (layout, backend_layout, ...) or introduce new fields.

You can define selectable values which determine multiple aspcts (HTML-template, CSS, Images, ...) or enable to select each value on its own.

Evaluation could be done in typoscript (don't worry about conditions, they are faster than stdWrap.if) or in fluid (e.g. selecting individual partials)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you think about an extra table? The information will be stored in the root page. For each template I have to save about 10 different pids, 2 Links in the header,  4 Links in the footer to social media, 4 headlines in the footer, 2 RTE and 3 images. To create extra fields for this in pages or tt_content extend this tables maybe to much, if I only need this information ones a time.

Comment: Those extra fields do not cost much space if it are only ints (blobs might be different). Even images are not much space as you store only a reference counter (the reference might be in sys_file_reference) (field slides). For header and footer content I would use common (or special?) CEs in special columns on the root page (special BE-layout) which gets inherited to all subpages (no column visible in BE-layout) (simple content slides)